# DataGridView and adding columns programmatically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to use a the `DataGridView` control to display a large number of columns. I have a `DataGridViewCell` class that specifies a custom Paint method for each cell. I have added the columns like so...

```
        int ColumnCount = 5000;
        DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn() { CellTemplate = cell, FillWeight = 1 });
        }
```

The problem is, this takes ages to add all the columns, much longer than it should really take. When I add the columns I can see the size of the scroll bar at the bottom of the `DataGridView` getting smaller like the grid is drawing each column each time I add one.

Does anyone know of a quicker way to add a large number of columns, or how to prevent the `DataGridView` updating until all the columns have been added?

I've tried disabling resizing, `SuspendLayout()`, and setting `dataGridView1.Visible = false`.

Comment: Try creating the column array collection and then add it to the grid instead of adding it to the grid in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the VirtualMode = TRUE for the DataGridView, you can refresh ONLY the screen portion.